# Is there any way to know the storage account name when ADF pipeline is triggered using ADF Storage Event Trigger

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a ADF Pipeline which gets triggered as soon as a file in uploaded into a storage account. After triggering some operations are performed. I am able to get folder path and file name of the uploaded file. I also wanted to get the storage account name as it is useful in the future processes. Is there any way to extract that.

Comment: You can create a pipeline parameter or global parameter and assign the storage account name to that and access it inside pipeline when required

Comment: This can be used if only a single  storage event trigger is applied. In case of multiple triggers from different storage accounts applied over a single pipeline, it will not work

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no option to fetch the storage account name directly from storage event triggers.

As a workaround, you can create a pipeline parameter to store the storage account name and pass the value from the event trigger when creating it.

1. **Creating event trigger:**

- Here as we are selecting the storage name manually, pass the same
  storage name value to the parameter.

[image]

- Here, in the value option provide the storage account name.

  [image]

2. **Create a parameter** in the pipeline to pull the storage name from the trigger.

[image]

3. Use the `Set variable` activity to show the parameter value which is passed from the trigger.

[image]